# Session gets empty

Tags: session, coldfusion

I have found out that session gets empty(empty structure) in a random moment, in application.cfm, and also after executing application.cfm.

Is there a way to secure the session? Or any other advices

Comment: what is your Sessiontimeout? When this time is over the session will reset

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the session is empty?

Comment: Sessiontimeout is set with`CreateTimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0)`. I see error that some field in session is undefined, in one of several places. I dumped the session, it was empty. But error occurrs time to time

Comment: Your session will timeout in 2hours. If you or a user opens a page, then you wait for 2 hours, the next page you load will get an empty session.

Comment: Look for code that either deletes or clears the session structure.

Comment: Does your ColdFusion server sit behind a load balancer?

Comment: @XavierL. this just logs user out, error can appear more often than once in 2 hours

Comment: @Miguel-F I'm not aware what is load balancer